# Weird line sticking out on the end of UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, tableview

[image]

I have a UILabel on each section of my tableview. I have this line sticking out on the end of the label and this is coming from an iPhone 6. I've encountered it before on the iPhone 5 and managed to make it disappear by changing the width of the UILabel.

Here's the code on viewForHeaderInSection:

```
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, 30))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 248/255, green: 247/255, blue: 243/255, alpha: 1.0)

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.width - (self.view.bounds.width * 0.4)) / 2, 0, self.view.bounds.width * 0.4, 25))
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 248/255, green: 247/255, blue: 243/255, alpha: 1.0)

    label.textColor = UIColor(red: 163/255, green: 144/255, blue: 99/255, alpha: 1.0)
    label.textAlignment = .Center

    label.text = "YOUR TITLE HERE"

    let line1 = UIView(frame: CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.width - (self.view.bounds.width * 0.8)) / 2, 13, self.view.bounds.width * 0.8, 1))
    line1.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 163/255, green: 144/255, blue: 99/255, alpha: 1.0)

    view.addSubview(line1) // Adds the line first

    view.addSubview(label) // Then the label on top of the line for the look.

    return view
```

Comment: Removing the background color of the label seems made it disappear. Don't know why it does this. It's not like there's a shadow on this thing or an outline to it.

Comment: I only get this effect on an iPhone6+, works fine on an iPhone 5 & 6 in the simulator. The only way I could stop it appearing on an iPhone6+ was to remove the background color of the label.

Comment: You saw it too? it's so weird. Anyway, i guess I have find a work around on this.